# How do you put an onclick on a js button

Tags: javascript, html

I have some js created buttons from GeeksforGeeks, but I don't know how to put on click on the buttons. I can create a button using the code I found online, but there was no explanation on how to make that button have on click function

Comment: You can bind click event listener to the button and add your logic in the click handler.

Comment: Please be specific on StackOverflow , so that other can understand, provide some code so that others can visualize your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let btn = document.createElement("button"); 
btn.innerHTML = 'hello';
btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
  console.log('click clock!');
});
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

This is how you should implement.
`btn.addEventListener('click',funcName)`;

ex.

```
function onClick(){
   //Your Code..
}
btn.addEventListener('click',onClick);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is as simple as below:

```
<button id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="getData();">Submit</button>

function getData(){
// your logic  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <button id="btnDemo">On-click Demo</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

java script Code :

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btnDemo');
btn.onClick = function(){
  alert('button is clicked..');
}
```

Jquery Code :

```
var btn = $('#btnDemo');
btn.click(function(){
  alert('button is clicked..');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<button id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="getData();">Submit</button>

function getData(){
--write here

}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with JS and jQuery both, check both the solutions.

For JS use `onlick` on button , with jQuery use `.click` function

```js
function runMe(){
 alert('I am executed with Pure JS');
}

$('document').ready(function(){
  $('#jQueryBubmit').click(function(){
    alert('I am executed with jQuery');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="runMe();">Submit</button>

<button id="jQueryBubmit" value="Submit">Submit with jQuery</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>

    <script>

        var button = document.createElement('BUTTON');
        button.setAttribute('id','btn');
        document.body.appendChild(button);

        var buttonById = document.getElementById('btn');
        buttonById.textContent = 'button is not clicked';

        buttonById.addEventListener('click',buttonClickFuntion);

        function buttonClickFuntion() {
            buttonById.textContent = 'button clicked';
        }

    </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The **onclick="java_script_function()"** attribute can be used for handling click event on a button.

**Here is a working example:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <button onclick="clickDemo()">On-click Demo</button>
        <hr>
        <span id="result"></span>
        <script>
            function clickDemo() {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Button was clicked";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image]

**More information:**

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp